# How can a Gamepanel expands to the object inside?

Tags: java, swing, height, expand, preferredsize

I want to make a game where you fly as a helicopter or rocket into the sky.
At the moment I can fly over the screen and placed "borders" if you fly against the maximum panelsize. I want that if the helicopter is at 50% of the Panelheight the background etc. goes down as much you fly hight.

Example:

Size: 600/600

When you start you are at x= 300 and y = 600 (bottem)
at this moment you can see the startpostion, trees, cars, etc.
If you fly higher than y = 300 the bottem slowly disapears and new objects apear etc.

I am very sorry for my english and I have no idea how I can explain it better.

Hope you can help me

Comment: Please do add, what are you using `AWT/Swing/JavaFX/OrSomethingElse`? Seems like you are in need of this [thingy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13328307/1057230), as explained in the thread :-)

Comment: I am using swing JPanel/JFrame